# Magento table tfoot location

Tags: magento

Where is the below? I've been looking for but cannot locate where this is.
It is a tfoot of order table in view order of my account page. Subtotal/ Shipping & Handling/Grand Total row

---

```
<tfoot>
            <tr class="subtotal">
    <td colspan="4" class="a-right">
                    Subtotal                    </td>
    <td class="last a-right">
                    <span class="price">$5,500.00</span>                    </td>
</tr>
        <tr class="shipping">
    <td colspan="4" class="a-right">
                    Shipping &amp; Handling                    </td>
    <td class="last a-right">
                    <span class="price">$156.00</span>                    </td>
</tr>
        <tr class="grand_total">
    <td colspan="4" class="a-right">
                    <strong>Grand Total</strong>
                </td>
    <td class="last a-right">
                    <strong><span class="price">$5,656.00</span></strong>
                </td>
</tr>
    </tfoot>
```

---

I would like to change the column span from "4" to "3".
Because I removed "SKU" low on the td/tr.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your respective theme folder's layout go to sales.xml and search for tag `sales_order_view` In it search for line `<block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">` under this defined block will be a line `<action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" class="a-right"</value></action>` you can change the colspan value from here.